# Word Request— word for fumbling and being clumsy with pronunciation

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I was wondering for a long while, and I can't seem to find the word.

I'm thinking of the way people, when feeling strong emotion, replace 'r's with 'w's, and generally are clumsy with their pronunciation.

Maybe, as I mentioned above, clumsy with words— but I feel that has another meaning.

I can do well with just explicitly telling them their pronunciation was tumbling all over the place, but I believe in the show don't tell technique and wanna follow it throughout my writing.

Edit: trill?

Comment: Replacing "r" with "w" has a specific name, a Rhotacism. Is that what you mean, or are you looking for something more general?

Comment: Rhotacism does sound similar, but I'm not looking for that kind of word. A verb maybe. I apologize if I sound picky by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [slurring](https://www.buoyhealth.com/learn/slurred-speech/) your words:

> Slurring your words can be commonly caused by exhaustion or alcohol consumption.

[Buoy Health](https://www.buoyhealth.com/learn/slurred-speech/)

Or as an adjective:

> Slurred speech is a symptom characterized by poor pronunciation of words, mumbling, or a change in speed or rhythm during talking. The medical term for slurred speech is dysarthria.

[Healthgrades](https://www.healthgrades.com/right-care/symptoms-and-conditions/slurred-speech)